# Send data from CSV file to SQL Server automatically?

Tags: sql, sql-server, python-3.x, database

I have a table in SQL Server where I need to insert data on regular base. Each day I perform same task importing data manually, it makes me feel tedious so I need your help. Is it possible to send data from CSV file to SQL Server's existing table without doing manual procedure.

Or using python to create a scrip that send data from CSV file to SQL Server at fixed time automatically.

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Depending on what version of SQL Server you have (ie. is it Standard or Enterprise?), you could just have a SQL Agent job that runs the import.  Either a simple SSIS package, or just a SQL command that runs a "bcp" - you could look into either of those options.  (If, by chance, you're only running SQL Express, then using SQL Agent won't be an option for you.  However, you could just run a Windows scheduled task with the "bcp")

Comment: Could you try to make a simple winform application?

Comment: I have sql Express version.

Comment: I have not tried for winform application. my task is to try to create something in sql server that perform this operation.

Comment: But there is nothing in the Express edition of sql server that will do something based on the passage of time (i.e., a schedule). Normally one uses the SQL Server Agent for that but it is not supported in the express edition. There are numerous discussions / solutions you can find by simply searching the internet.

Comment: Thanks I found out another way to send csv file to existing table by just running query once.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to create a python script that inserts data into **SQL** server after reading **CSV** file. Then you should create a **CRON** job on your server that runs this script regularly. This might be a possible solution for your problem.